# How do I remove settings icon (overflow menu) on top-right of action bar?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

How do I remove the settings icon from the top-right of the action bar?  When I emulate on my actual Samsung galaxy s3 phone, it is not there, however, when I emulate on an AVD for the Nexus 7, it appears.  Here is the code for my menu:

```xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/main_menu_actionbutton"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/Menu"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: well just delete that item

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you mean the three dots, that's called the overflow menu. It exists on devices which do not have a hardware menu button - which your Galaxy S3 has, while the Nexus 7 does not. So on your S3 you press the menu button and get the popup at the bottom, but on the Nexus you press the 3 dots and get the overflow popup dropping down from the action bar. If it wasn't there, how would you be able to access overflow items?

If you'd simply like to remove it altogether, just delete the first `<item />` entry in the `menu.xml` you posted.

Comment: Is there any example please help me

Answer (score 30):

There are two methods in your "MainActivity" java class. They are called onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected. These are usually added by IDEs like Eclipse when you use the default settings to create an Activity in your project. The methods look like the ones shown below.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

These methods create the menu items and insert code for what is to be done when one of the menu items are clicked. Just remove or comment out these two methods and you should see that the menu button will vanish. The XMLs can still have them just in case you want your menu items or menu back.

Answer (score 3):

as android:showAsAction for the following item is set to never this item becomes part of overflow menu.
set this to always or ifroom r remove this item and it will work

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
```